# If I update a parent object with a reference to a child object, will it update the child?

Tags: apex

Example code:

```
List<Parent> parents = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Children) FROM Parent];

for (Parent p:parents)
{
    for (Child c:p.Children)
    {
        //Some code, changes fields on children
    }
}

update parents;
```

Would the update on the parent object update the child objects as well, as the Children list is referenced in the parent object? Or do I have to explicitly tell salesforce which objects to update?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Realistically, the only thing that would update as you describe would be limited to a formula, only because formulas are generated on the fly. So if from your child you are pulling things down from the parent, your formula is always auto-generated every time you request it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put No, you cannot update through relationships like that.

Likewise if you did

```
List<Child> Children= [SELECT Id, Parent__r.Name FROM Child];

for (Child c : Children)
{
   c.Parent__r.Name = 'New Name'
}

update children;
```

Will not update the Parent's Name field.